# C Array Count (Beginner)

Tags: c, arrays, kernighan-and-ritchie

I'm currently reading 'The C Programming Language' by Kernighan & Richie and I'm struggling to work out what a line does. I think I'm just being a little stupid, and not quite understanding their explanation.

```
++ndigit[c-'0'];
```

I've had to change the program ever so slightly as `ndigit` was previously giving me garbage values, so I just instantiate the array to 0, instead of traversing it with a for loop, and changing the values that way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int c, i, nwhite, nother;
    int ndigit[10]= {0};

    nwhite = nother = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            ++ndigit[c-'0'];
        else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            ++nwhite;
        else
            ++nother;

    printf("digits =");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        printf (" %d", ndigit[i]);
    printf (", white space = %d, other = %d\n", nwhite, nother);
}
```

Using the program as its input, we get this printed to the console  -

```
digits = 7 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1, white space = 104, other = 291
```

I understand that `7 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1` is a count of how many times the single numbers appear in the input 0 appears 7 times, 1 appears twice etc.)

But, how does the `...[c-'0'];` 'work'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked how the below expression works

```
 c-'0'
```

The ASCII code  of the entered charecter is subtracted from the ASCII code  of 0 and it defines the position in the array where the count has to be stored .

Suppose you enter **1** from the keyboard ASCII code for **1** is 49 and ASCII code for **0** is 48. 
hence

```
   49-48 =1
```

and the count will be stored in the array index location 1 .

Comment: The C standard does not require that ASCII be used. The C standard does require that the characters '0' to '9' have consecutive values.

Comment: Note: this is only works with a continuous character set (such as ASCII)

Answer (score 3):

`c-'0'` is technique to give int value == to char number e.g. `1` for `'1'` , `5` for `'5'`.

char symbols `'0', '1', '2' ..... '9'` are assigned continue encoding values so difference of a numeric char constant with `'0'` gives decimal number. (in your compiler for example in ASCII char they are assigned continues acsii values).

So for example in variable `c` is `'7'`, then `c - '0'` == `7`;

In your code array declared as:

```
int ndigit[10]= {0};   
                // default initialized with `0`
```

So index can be from `0` to `9`.  So in you code:

```
++ndigit[c-'0'];  // ndigit[c-'0'] = ndigit[c-'0'] + 1;
```

increments frequency  of a number by `1` when at corresponding digit of a number char.

Comment: The C standard does not require that ASCII be used. The C standard does require that the characters '0' to '9' have consecutive values.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks again! ok is it because it can be use other encoding?

Comment: Yes, I believe IBM still has a compiler that uses EBCDIC encoding, and C implementations for embedded processors may use unusual character sets. Or, in theory, you could modify GCC to use something other than ASCII and still be in conformance with the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil tried to write correct a bit so it not mislead..

Answer (score 3):

In C, when you have a variable `c` of type char, it actually stores some integer encoding of the char (usually the [ASCII](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Standard_Code_for_Information_Interchange) code). So `c-'0'` means the difference of the code of the character contained in `c` and the character `0`. Since the digits are in natural order it convert the digit in the associated number.

Answer (score 2):

The C standard requires that the characters '0' to '9' have consecutive values.

`'0'` represents the value zero as a character and c is the value you enter it calculates to be like this :

> '1' - '0' == 1
>
> '2' - '0' == 2

and so on ... i.e equal to the value of `c` if `c` is a **digit**

Answer (score 2):

Ascii is an encoding which gives consecutive id's to consecutive digits. As Eric Postpischil pointed out, the standard demands that property, even though the underlying encoding need not be ascii. Ascii is quite common though.

```
char c1 = '0';
char c2 = '1';
```

So whatever number `'0'` is mapped to, `'1'` will be that number + 1. In essence:

```
c2 == c1 + 1
```

Subtracting `'0'` from a character which is a digit, will return its numeric value:

```
'1' - '0' == 1
```

Comment: The C standard does not require that ASCII be used. The C standard does require that the characters '0' to '9' have consecutive values.

Answer (score 1):

Loog at ASCII [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

> The American Standard Code for Information Interchange (ASCII /ˈæski/ ass-kee)[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is a character-encoding scheme originally based on the English alphabet that encodes 128 specified characters - the numbers 0-9, the letters a-z and A-Z, some basic punctuation symbols, some control codes that originated with Teletype machines, and a blank space - into the 7-bit binary integers.

So In the ASCII Scheme the '0' char is the number 48, the char '1' is 41, and so on. So c - '0' is equivalent to c - 48. If c is '1' the expression became 49 - 48 = 1. So in few word 'c' - '0' convert a digit char ['0'-'9'] into an integer [0-9].

**Edit 1** 
As suggested by @Eric Postpischil, ASCII is not part of ANSi C (nor c++). But is very common and all compiler I know use ASCII set.

Comment: The C standard does not require that ASCII be used. The C standard does require that the characters '0' to '9' have consecutive values.

Answer (score 1):

```
((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            ++ndigit[c-'0'];
```

`c` gives you the current character. With the range checking you confirm it is a number [by using its ASCII value](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif)
<sub>Check `chr` column for `0`, it says `48` and for `8` it says `56`.So, `'8'- '0'` gives `56 - 48` = `8`</sub>

`ndigit` is used to keep track of how many times a number occurs in with each element of the array representing the number of times its subscript has occured.
`ndigit[0]` will ggive you number of times `0` has occurred and so on.. `ndigit[x]` gives number of times `x` appeared

```
[c - '0']
```

suppose your `c` i.e current character is `8` then `'8' - '0'` will give you `8`. so you get `ndigit[8]` and you `++` that value [you initialised it to `0` at start]

Comment: The C standard does not require that ASCII be used. The C standard does require that the characters '0' to '9' have consecutive values.

Answer (score 0):

'0' is a char and it has value 48. You can look up any ASCII table in the google.
It works this way because you read from the input char value not the int, so if you don't add "-'0'" part it will increment 48th cell of an array. 
Instead of "-'0'" you can put "-48", in my opinion it's more readable this way.

Comment: The C standard does not require that ASCII be used. The C standard does require that the characters '0' to '9' have consecutive values.